# Reverse a match or match every element in an array where some IDs are not set

Tags: arrays, json, elasticsearch, nested, elasticsearch-painless

Struggling with making this ES query. Basically, I have a nested object, something like:

```json
{
  "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
  "exchangeRate": 0.01,
  "payments": [
    {
      "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "paymentId": "some-id",
      "currency": "USD",
      "amount": 400.0
    },
    {
      "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "currency": "USD",
      "paymentId": "some-id2",
      "amount": -200.0
    },
    {
      "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "currency": "USD",
      "amount": -200.0
    }
  ]
}
```

And I want to match on an object where some of the "paymentId" keys are defined, but not all. So the above object would be a match. Whereas something like:

```json
{
  "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
  "exchangeRate": 0.01,
  "payments": [
    {
      "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "paymentId": "some-id",
      "currency": "USD",
      "amount": 400.0
    },
    {
      "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "currency": "USD",
      "paymentId": "some-id2",
      "amount": -200.0
    },
    {
      "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "currency": "USD",
      "paymentId": "some-id3",
      "amount": -200.0
    }
```

Would not match.

I've made a query which matches if all paymendIds are defined and returns all objects where that is true. This query is:

```json
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "payments",
          "query": {
            "exists": {
              "field": "payments.paymendIds"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The question would be how do I reverse this? So that if it matches this query, it doesn't return as a match. As putting "must_not" simply does the opposite. It returns all records that don't have any paymentIds defined at all. Which is something I want to match on, but I need all the ones that even have only *some* of the paymentIds set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could compare the `payments` objects' **[field value sizes](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch/7.0.0/org/elasticsearch/index/fielddata/ScriptDocValues.html)** one by one while in the `nested` context.

Assuming both `payments.id` and `payments.paymentId` are of the `keyword` mapping type, you could say:

```json
GET your-index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "payments",
      "query": {
        "script": {
          "script": "doc['payments.id'].size() != doc['payments.paymentId'].size()"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```